# search for text in folder containing zip files and if matched, copy the files to a location

Tags: powershell

PowerShell script to search text inside a folder containing zip files and copy the files to a location if found matching.

Till now I got up to searching in folder. How to proceed further?

```
$logs = Get-ChildItem $path |
        where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt ($FromTime)} |
        where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt ($ToTime)} |
        Select-String -Pattern $Searchstring |
        Select-Object Filename |
        Format-list
```

Comment: You would have to uncompress the archive and then search its contents.

Comment: Matt wins, you can't copy uncompressed files individually

Comment: You have a logs folder full of zip files? It looks to me like the search you are doing is on the (zip) file name, and you want to copy any zip file matching a certain text pattern? Or do you actually need to search the files *inside* the zips?

Comment: I have a folder full of zip folders. There are many files under that zip folders. i need to search text inside the files and copy files having that text.